# How to change part of the schema in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I was trying to change a line of schema.rb (t.string must become t.text) but I can't change it directly through the file because when I use rake db:migrate the changes revert on the previous state.

How can I change that string?

EDIT: If I didn't misunderstood something, I must edit the file inside db/migrate. In my case is 2010110801532_create_posts.rb, where exactly I'll have to put the change_column part?

This is my **2010110801532_create_posts.rb**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :nome
      t.string :titolo
      t.text :contenuto

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :posts
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're using create_table, then you can set your column type there.  There's no need for a change_table.  change_table would be used if you already had a table with data in it in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step-by-step:

First, generate a new migration:

```
./script/generate migration change_string_to_text
```

In the generated migration file, `nnnnnnnnnnn_change_string_to_text.rb`, you need to add the line:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :text
```

Then do a `rake migrate` to apply the changes to the database.

Comment: Thank you! It was that simple (after the step-by-step! :D)

Comment: For completeness, I should mention that it's a good idea to put the inverse in the "down" method.

Comment: Rails 3 update: use `rails g` instead of `./script/generate`, and `rake db:migrate` instead of `rake migrate`.

Answer (score 3):

Make a migration to change it :) If you're using migrations, then it's not a good idea to edit the schema file directly.

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :text
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question because you surely was clear, but it's just my second day on Rails, and I can't follow your suggestion. Can you add some details please?

Answer (score 0):

The schema.rb file is auto generated by rake, so any changes you make will be overwritten.  As Matchu mentioned, a migration is the way to go, start with:

```
./script/generate migration change_string_to_text
```

Comment: Will this change any string to text? How can I select only the requested string to be changed into text?